# VBA - Searching the first repeated word within a Range

Tags: vba, excel

I've implemented this macro whereby if i run it, it will show me the column and row of the word "needle" in the range A1:Z20. Although if there are multiple words of "needle" it will only output the last. How can I change this code to show me the first occurrence of the word?

Hope this makes sense, and here is my code so far:

```
Sub NeedleSearch()
Dim SearchSpace As Variant
Dim found As Boolean
found = False
SearchSpace = Range("A1:z20").Value
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
For i = 1 To 20
    For j = 1 To 26
        If SearchSpace(i, j) = "needle" Then
            Range("A25").Value = "Column " & j
            Range("B25").Value = "Row " & i
            found = True
        End If
    Next j
Next i
If found = False Then
    Range("A25").Value = "needle not found"
    Range("B25").Value = " "
End If
End Sub
```

[With No Repeated Words](https://gyazo.com/b2b093ced12be97783f848f3f19c29f4)
[With 1 Repeated Word](https://gyazo.com/5a44fdd5daec3280a5698273c9bde621)

Comment: Add an `Exit For` after `found = True`

Comment: or use a `do until loop` `do....loop until found=true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only first occurense just quit your loops!

```
Sub NeedleSearch()
    Dim SearchSpace As Variant
    Dim found As Boolean
    found = False
    SearchSpace = Range("A1:z20").Value
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    For i = 1 To 20
        For j = 1 To 26
            If SearchSpace(i, j) = "needle" Then
                Range("A25").Value = "Column " & j
                Range("B25").Value = "Row " & i
                found = True
            End If
            If found Then _
                    Exit For
        Next j
        If found Then _
                Exit For
    Next i
    If found = False Then
        Range("A25").Value = "needle not found"
        Range("B25").Value = " "
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Aaah! Thank you very much, should of seen that.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate further: What this code actually does, if there are multiple instances of `needle` is, it will print all instances of found cells into A25:B25. Let's say there are 3 instances of `needle` e.g. in A1, B2 and C3. Your loop prints A1 into A25:B25 first, then B2 and then C3. Because it is happening so fast, you only see C3 or what you called the "last occurence".

What you can do to print out *all* solutions (which is what I'm guessing you're trying to do in the end) you could change your code to something like this:

```
Sub NeedleSearch()
Dim SearchSpace As Variant
Dim found As Boolean
found = False
SearchSpace = Range("A1:z20").Value
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
k = 25

For i = 1 To 20
    For j = 1 To 26
        If SearchSpace(i, j) = "needle" Then
            ws.Cells(k, 1).Value = "Occurence " & k - 24
            ws.Cells(k, 2).Value = "Column " & j
            ws.Cells(k, 3).Value = "Row " & i
            k = k + 1
            found = True
        End If
    Next j
Next i
If found = False Then
    ws.Range("A25").Value = "needle not found"
End If
End Sub
```

Change your `Sheet` ID accordingly.

HTH

Comment: Great, thanks very much! I also needed this as well :)

Comment: Great, happy to hear this. But please mark either one of the answer as correct so the question is flagged as 'already answered'. Cheerio :)

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid loops by means of [Find()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx) method of `Range` object:

```
Option Explicit

Sub NeedleSearch()
    Dim f As Range

    Set f = Range("A1:Z20").Find(what:="needle", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, After:=Range("Z20"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
    If f Is Nothing Then
        Range("A25").Value = "needle not found"
        Range("B25").Value = " "
    Else
        Range("A25").Value = "Column " & f.Column
        Range("B25").Value = "Row " & f.Row
    End If
End Sub
```

that can also be rewritten as follows:

```
Sub NeedleSearch()
    Dim f As Range
    Dim arr As Variant

    Set f = Range("A1:Z20").Find(what:="needle", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, After:=Range("Z20"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
    If f Is Nothing Then
        arr = Array("needle not found", " ")
    Else
        arr = Array("Column " & f.Column, "Row " & f.Row)
    End If
    Range("A25:B25").Value = arr
End Sub
```